# UIView convertPoint:toView for embedded views

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

I have 3 view controllers, their corresponding views, and an additional view on top of these views.

The main view controller has a container view with corresponding view controller

[image: View with container view as subview]

The container VC has a tableView in it

[image: Container View with UITableView as subview]

I want certain points within the `UITableView`'s individual cell's frames to be represented as points in the main view controller's Animations coordinate system.

I am using `convertPoint:toView` method. I am performing this in the main view controller. My question is should my code read like this?

```
[self.containerVC.tableVC.tableView convertPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame)) toView:self.animations];
```

like this?

```
[self.containerVC.tableVC.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame)) toView:self.animations];
```

or like this?

```
[self.containerVC.view convertPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame)) toView:self.animations];
```

The "frame" parameter comes from an array in which the individual cell frames from the UITableView are stored.

Comment: Are you asking which view should be responsible for performing the conversion?

Comment: Ping me if that doesn't answer your question, and if so please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you don't understand.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You obviously made a rash judgement of the question and did not even read the question which prevented other users from looking at the question which means that I didn't get an answer to my specific question in this case. The question is quite clear. If you cannot even bother to read the question or understand it, I suggest in the future you don't go around marking questions to your subjective judgement.

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, I was trying to help you get an answer as quickly as possible, and I even very politely told you to _just let me know_ if the linked question didn't solve your problem. Instead, you have decided to get mad at me. It's _not_ clear what you're asking; that's why I left my first comment above, so again, please [edit] to be more explicit about which part of the three lines of code you are trying to understand.